# Implementing Autocorrect Functionality in React.js Using Built-in Libraries

Tags: reactjs, autocorrect

Can autocorrect functionality be implemented in React.js using any built-in library? Additionally, please suggest scalable methods of implementation that are not too heavy. If not using a React.js library, are there any alternative methods available?

Comment: There is another method of implementing auto correct - by using a third party API. You can take the text that your user has typed in up to the last word and send it to auto correct API every 15 seconds if the input has changed since the last send. This way, the auto correct API will provide you with a list of suggestions, and you just have to visualize them in your text box.